# filter dataframe rows based on length of column values

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ [1,2], [np.NaN,1], ['test string1', 5]], columns=['A','B'] )

df
              A  B
0             1  2
1           NaN  1
2  test string1  5
```

I am using pandas 0.20. What is the most efficient way to remove any rows where 'any' of its column values has length > 10?

len('test string1')
12

So for the above e.g., I am expecting an output as follows:

```
df
              A  B
0             1  2
1           NaN  1
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If based on column `A`

```
In [865]: df[~(df.A.str.len() > 10)]
Out[865]:
     A  B
0    1  2
1  NaN  1
```

If based on all columns

```
In [866]: df[~df.applymap(lambda x: len(str(x)) > 10).any(axis=1)]
Out[866]:
     A  B
0    1  2
1  NaN  1
```

Answer (score 9):

I had to cast to a string for Diego's answer to work:

```
df = df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) <= 10)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
              A  B                         C          D
0             1  2                         2 2017-01-01
1           NaN  1                       NaN 2017-01-02
2  test string1  5  test string1test string1 2017-01-03

In [43]: df.dtypes
Out[43]:
A            object
B             int64
C            object
D    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [44]: df.loc[~df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.str.len().gt(10)).any(1)]
Out[44]:
     A  B    C          D
0    1  2    2 2017-01-01
1  NaN  1  NaN 2017-01-02
```

**Explanation:**

`df.select_dtypes(['object'])` selects only columns of `object` (`str`) dtype:

```
In [45]: df.select_dtypes(['object'])
Out[45]:
              A                         C
0             1                         2
1           NaN                       NaN
2  test string1  test string1test string1

In [46]: df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.str.len().gt(10))
Out[46]:
       A      C
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
```

now we can "aggregate" it as follows:

```
In [47]: df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.str.len().gt(10)).any(axis=1)
Out[47]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

finally we can select only those rows where value is `False`:

```
In [48]: df.loc[~df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.str.len().gt(10)).any(axis=1)]
Out[48]:
     A  B    C          D
0    1  2    2 2017-01-01
1  NaN  1  NaN 2017-01-02
```

Comment: `df[df.select_dtypes([object]).astype(str).applymap(len).le(10).all(1)]`

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you for the hint! Don't you think `.applymap()` will be slower?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It may have been improved in recent versions.  I was mostly just playing golf

Comment: @piRSquared, i see. I'm still using Pandas 0.19.2 and 0.20.1 ... I'll try to check `.applymap()` speed as soon as i upgrade to the latest Pandas version

Comment: `0.19.2` /shockface!  You've been exposed :-)

Comment: Question I didn't ask OP.  Are `NaN` zero length?

Comment: @piRSquared, no, their length is `NaN`. I mean `df[col].str.len()` returns `NaN` for `NaN` values

Answer (score 2):

Use the apply function of series, in order to keep them:

`df = df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: len(x) <= 10)]`

Comment: Thank you, all! I selected the solutions that are scalable to all columns.