# Python For Loop / List Comprehension copy multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, list-comprehension

I feel kinda stupid, but I haven't got this for hours now. I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns. Now, I want to iterate over the column "firstcol" and check a condition (here: length of the string and some more). The result should be copied to a new list/df.

```
result = [i for i in data["firstcol"] if (len(i)>5 and ...)]
```

The Problem: Now I missed the second column. But I want to copy the full row. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: It feels you are going about this the wrong way,can add in some sample data and a desired result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter dataframe rows based on length of column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089650/filter-dataframe-rows-based-on-length-of-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to loop all over the dataframe, instead you can just use the apply method and apply a function to the entire column.

Try something like this :

```
df_new = df[df['firstcol'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) > 5)]
```

Comment: You're my hero! :)